# VBScript get sum of values from WMI query loop

Tags: vbscript, wmi

The basic script shown below will echo the value of each objItem.MemoryDevices (M) it finds in colItems.  However, that's not what I want.  Since each value will always be a number, I want it to echo the total sum of all the values it finds.

```
strComputer = "."

Set objWMIService = GetObject( "winmgmts://" & strComputer & "/root/cimv2" )
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_PhysicalMemoryArray",,48 )


For Each objItem in colItems
    M = objItem.MemoryDevices
    Wscript.Echo M
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBScript will automatically convert between string and numerical types. You should be able to accomplish what you want by adding a Total set to a number, then increment the Total by your variable M.

```
strComputer = "."

Set objWMIService = GetObject( "winmgmts://" & strComputer & "/root/cimv2" )
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM 
Win32_PhysicalMemoryArray",,48 )

Total = 0
For Each objItem in colItems
    M = objItem.MemoryDevices
    Total = Total + M
Next

WScript.Echo Total
```